# как запустить скрипт на pypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy

скачал архив pypy с офф сайта, разархивировал - дальше стало туго
как устанавливать дальше не понял, документация не помогает.
пробовал сделать по пунктам как описано тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893317/how-to-use-pypy-on-windows
но консоль говорит, что не знает pypy, python ставил с анакондой.
может кто-нибудь по пунктам расписать как установить и запустить скрипт?

Comment: Ну вот, уже хоть какой-то конструктив появился. Дайте содержимое переменной окружения PATH и путь, где лежит ваш pypy

Comment: @andreymal в Path прописан путь  C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\pypy3-v5.8.0-src , pypy в данный момент лежит там же.
если надо могу остальные пути скинуть

Comment: А зачем вы src скачали-то, надо же качать скомпилированную версию для windows

Comment: @andreymal я не видел ссылки на скачивания там другие...http://pypy.org/download.html

Comment: Там есть ссылка «Windows binary (32bit)»

Comment: Если вам нужен именно pypy3, то тогда уже проблема (я тоже не вижу там бинарников для винды), но тогда и вопрос должен звучать по-другому, например «где найти бинарники pypy3 под windows» или «как собрать windows-версию pypy3 из исходников». А как собрать — это есть в документации :)

Comment: И вообще зачем вам pypy)

Comment: @andreymal  у меня парсер файла и включенных в него файлов(отрабатывает за 900 секунд где-то), я прочитал, что pypy может ускорить работу, хотел попробовать ускорить , почитал и прочитал что pypy быстрее cpython(не первым , ни вторым не пользовался)

Comment: @andreymal ты не знаешь случайно, как собрать?
у меня  не выходит=/(не понимаю как собрать согласно инструкции)

Comment: Не знаю . . . . .

Comment: тогда буду дальше искать...

Comment: @ddsds, `почитал и прочитал что pypy быстрее cpython(не первым , ни вторым не пользовался)` подозреваю, что скрипт вы запускали как раз с помощью CPython (это "стандартная" реализация Python). Вообще, если у вас обрабатывается много файлов, то скорее все упирается в производительность устройства хранения/файловой системы, так что просто замена интерпретатора может не дать повышения производительности. А изменение алгоритма на более оптимальный наоборот может дать многократное повышение производительности.